# Foreach repeats the inner values...this one should be easy!

Tags: c#

```
float [] pt1x = {0.580f, 0.680f, 0.780f}; 
float [] pt1y = {1.128f, 1.228f, 1.328f}; 

foreach (float xpt in pt1x) {
   System.Console.WriteLine("xpt = " + xpt);
       foreach (float ypt in pt1y) {
        System.Console.WriteLine("ypt = " + ypt);
      }  
}

------my output:
xpt = 0.58
ypt = 1.128
ypt = 1.228
ypt = 1.328
xpt = 0.68
ypt = 1.128
ypt = 1.228
ypt = 1.328
xpt = 0.78
ypt = 1.128
ypt = 1.228
ypt = 1.328
---------------here is what I NEED

 to get below:
xpt = 0.58
ypt = 1.128
xpt = 0.68
ypt = 1.228
xpt = 0.78
ypt = 1.328
```

Comment: You've been on the site for 41 days and posted 12 questions. With respect, by now you should know how to ensure that code in a question is readable: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help *Update*: ArsenMkrt has been kind enough to do it for you on this occasion, but it would be better if you did it yourself going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nested loop isn't what you want here.  The inner loop is going to run in its entirety for each element of the outer loop.

If both your arrays have the same number of elements, just do one loop, and do all your operations on both arrays at the same time.

```
for (int i = 0; i < pt1x.Length; i++)
{
   System.Console.WriteLine("xpt = " + pt1x[i]);
   System.Console.WriteLine("ypt = " + pt1y[i]);
}
```

Comment: This gave me exactly what I needed (with a slight edit here):

for (int i = 0; i < pt1x.Length; i++)
    {
      System.Console.WriteLine("xpt = " + pt1x[i]);
      System.Console.WriteLine("ypt = " + pt1y[i]);
    }

Comment: Whups, sorry that was a typo.

Answer (score 6):

```
float [] pt1x = {0.580f, 0.680f, 0.780f};  
float [] pt1y = {1.128f, 1.228f, 1.328f};  

    for (int i=0; i < pt1x.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Writeline("xpt = " + pt1x[i]);
        Console.Writeline("ypt = " + pt1y[i]);
    }
```

Comment: This is a perfectly acceptable solution given the provided inputs; see my answer for an alternative that utilizes the same approach but with additional safeguards in place (e.g., checking the lengths of the arrays) and for a variable number of inputs.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < pt1x.Length; i++)
 Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}",pt1x[i],pt1y[i]);
```

you were doing: (note the indentation)

```
  for each x
    print x
    for each y
       print y
```

but you should use System.Drawing.Point

Answer (score 2):

If you make the move to .NET 4.0 you can use the [Enumerable.Zip method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28VS.100%29.aspx), otherwise you can implement it as an extension method in .NET 3.5. An example of such an implementation is given by Eric Lippert in his blog post: [Zip Me Up](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/07/zip-me-up.aspx).

Here's how it would be used:

```
float[] pt1x = {0.580f, 0.680f, 0.780f}; 
float[] pt1y = {1.128f, 1.228f, 1.328f}; 

var result = pt1x.Zip(pt1y, (xpt, ypt) =>
                    "xpt = " + xpt + Environment.NewLine + "ypt = " + ypt);

foreach (var item in result)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Note that you may want to change `xpt` to `xpt.ToString()` (same for `ypt`) in the concatenation portion of the lambda expression to have better control over the return type.

EDIT: switched implementation link to Eric Lippert's post since it checks for arguments before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat robust solution (uses the same principle as others have already provided, but for an arbitrary number of arrays):

```
static IEnumerable<T[]> AlignArrays<T>(params T[][] arrays) {
    if (arrays == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("arrays");

    int numArrays = arrays.Length;
    if (numArrays < 1)
        yield break;

    T[] firstArray = arrays[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.Length; ++i) {
        T[] aligned = new T[numArrays];

        for (int j = 0; j < numArrays; ++j) {
            T[] thisArray = arrays[j];

            if (i < thisArray.Length)
                aligned[j] = thisArray[i];
            else
                aligned[j] = default(T);
        }

        yield return aligned;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
float [] pt1x = {0.580f, 0.680f, 0.780f}; 
float [] pt1y = {1.128f, 1.228f, 1.328f}; 

foreach (float[] aligned in AlignArrays<float>(pt1x, pt1y)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < aligned.Length; ++i)
        Console.WriteLine(aligned[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
0.580
1.128
0.680
1.228
0.780
1.328
```

Answer (score -1):

This looks like value pairs. Wouldn't a `Dictionary<float, float>` be better?

```
Dictionary<float, float> floats = new Dictionary<float, float>();

            floats.Add(0.580f, 1.128f);
            floats.Add(0.680f, 1.228f);
            floats.Add(0.780f, 1.328f);

            floats.Keys.ToList().ForEach(f =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("key: {0} value: {1}", f, floats[f]));
                });
```

Comment: I would be more inclined to use PointF.